# Execl and printing of child PID

Tags: c, linux, if-statement

I am trying to get the PID of the child process. 
But when I run execl, it prints out the PID of 0 and sometimes negative numbers instead of the real PID.
However, if I remove the execl line, it works fine.
Anyone knows why?

```
if (pid==0)
            { 
                    arrayPID[i] = getpid();
                 execl("/bin/ls","/bin/ls",NULL); 
            }

             printf ("Child PID is %i\n",arrayPID[i]);
```

Note that I know that the 2nd parameter of execl should be just "ls" but it seems to be working and I need it to be that way. Is it because of this?

I have also tried this but still give zero or negative values for PID.

```
if (pid==0)
            { 
                    arrayPID[i] = getpid(); 
            }
if (pid==0)
            { 
                 execl("/bin/ls","/bin/ls",NULL); 
            }
```

Do assume my other code is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` returns the PID of the child process to the parent process.  Calling `getpid` in the child doesn't do anything.

What I guess you're looking for is:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    // child
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
}
else if (pid > 0)
{
    // parent
    printf("Child PID is %d\n", (int)pid);
}
else
{
    // error
    perror("fork failed");
}
```

Comment: It gives me the PID of the child process?

Comment: fork only returns values like zero so we know its a child. I need the actual PID

Comment: @Newbie, `fork()` returns zero in the child.  In the parent, it returns the child's PID.

Comment: @Carl Norum the above should probably be amended to "Calling getpid in the child doesn't do anything *as you are using it.*"

Comment: @Newbie It is as it is: the parent needs the child's PID as it needs it for `wait()` or so. The child doesn't need the parent's PID, and if it needs it, it can be given it via a variable which is initialized before `fork()`, or just with `getppid()`. And everyone can get its own PID with `getpid()`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a sneaking suspicion as to what might be happening. This extends Carl's answer some.

Assuming your code does something like this...(I can't be 100% sure without more details)

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    arrayPID[i] = getpid();
    execl("/bin/ls","/bin/ls",NULL);
}
printf ("Child PID is %i\n",arrayPID[i]);
```

The issue is that you only enter that `if` statement in the child process, but not the parent process. The child process will call `execl` and unless something goes wrong, never reach the `printf` (though even if it does, it will print what you want).

Hence, in the *parent* process, if you did not initialize `arrayPID[i]` before this section of code, it'll still be uninitialized when it reaches the `printf`, and thus basically print out garbage (though I suppose 0 being most common isn't unusual).